# Adding tab to QTabWidget. is empty?

Tags: qt, tabs, qwidget

Well, the thing is I have a `tabwidget` created in qtcreator, with many tabs and in the tabs there are many lineedit and other objects.
The closeable property of the `tabWidget` is set to `true`.
I execute the program and close the tabs, but when I want to reopen the tab, it's empty, I'm using this code:

```
tabs->addTab(new QWidget(),"TAB 1");
```

I want to use the same tab create on the design of qtcreator.

Comment: Well. I found the solution: ui->tabWidget->addTab(ui->name_tab,QIcon("icon.png"),"NAMETAB");

Comment: Post it as an answer other people could easily find and use it in future

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are adding empty widget in your code:

```
tabs->addTab(new QWidget(),"TAB 1");
```

Instead you need to keep you widgets and add them like that:

```
QWidget* widget; // it is stored
int index = ui->tabWidget->addTab(widget, "TAB 1");
```

Where to take these widgets?

It is not enough to set closable to true, you also to use signal/slot:

```
connect(ui->tabWidget, SIGNAL(tabCloseRequested(int)), this, SLOT(closeTab(int)));
```

And finally:

```
void YourWindow::closeTab(int index)
{
    // do something else

    QWidget* widget = ui->tabWidget->widget(index);
    ui->tabWidget->removeTab(index);

    // here you can remember it and use later when adding tab
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good, just for the last tab that the user close, but not to a particular tab.

Comment: OK, I thought it is up to you to store widgets correctly. I didn't mean storing only the last tab